# JDBC connection error only while starting docker-compose

Tags: java, mysql, docker, war

Why when I am running docker-compose with the file below, and I am trying to run `localhost:8080/todo-application-1.0/` I am getting internal error within is mentioned that jdbc cannot connect. But when I am running the same docker-compose file without `web` service I am able to connect to the database, can anyone explain to me what is wrong? How to successfully create a docker-compose or dockerfile that will copy the .war with the application and run it without any issues with the connection.

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  database:
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'todo-app'
      MYSQL_USER: 'admin'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'admin'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'admin'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      - '3306'
  web:
    image: tomcat
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./build/libs/todo-application-1.0.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/todo-application-1.0.war
```

Comment: please provide additional info. what does mean 'web'? where from do you run? 
what is the exact exception?
Basic advice - go step by step and leave info here